# Get Facebook page rating comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieved comments from a page rating.

I'm getting page ratings from endpoind `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/21[...]58/ratings?fields=created_time,has_rating,has_review,open_graph_story,rating,recommendation_type,review_text,reviewer`

I get an array of rating object, with this rating for example:

```json
{
  "created_time": "2021-11-06T04:20:20+0000",
  "has_rating": false,
  "has_review": true,
  "open_graph_story": {
    "id": "21[...]58",
    "message": "Lorem ipsum",
    "start_time": "2021-12-26T21:14:02+0000",
    "type": "sellers.rates",
    "data": {
      "recommendation_type": "positive",
      "review_text": "Lorem ipsum",
      "is_hidden": false,
      "language": "fr",
      "seller": {
        "id": "54[...]12",
        "title": "LOREM",
        "type": "place",
        "url": "https://facebook.com/lorem"
      },
      "has_review_update": false
    }
  },
  "recommendation_type": "positive",
  "review_text": "Lorem ipsum",
  "reviewer": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": "56[...]60"
  }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to get comments from this review by requesting `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/54[...]12_21[...]58/comments`

But I get this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID ' 54[...]12_21[...]58' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "Av[...]fN"
  }
}
```

In the other hand, this request working fine with a "classic" post.

Does that means ratings are not concidered as a post ?
How can I get comments from rating ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/recommendation/

The Graph API docs do not mention any comments endpoint/edges for a single recommendation, so I assume it is not possible to get them.

Compare the docs to the page post docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/#edges

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is the mixup of identifiers. Looks like you're concatenating page ID and recommendation ID with `_` and FB does not recognize it.

Recommendation comments can be retrieved using the `open_graph_story` identifier:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/21[...]58/comments
```